# reading infrared remote control from Nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, infrared, remote-control, input-devices

I would like to ask you, if it's possible to read the infrared remote control signal from an APP programmed in Nativescript, and how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably. Try using the [native API access via Typescript](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript.html#intellisense-and-access-to-native-apis-via-typescript) which might then get you access to the [ConsumerIrManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager.html) which is where you should start for IR transmission